# XML xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation path

Tags: xml

I have the following XML:

```
<products xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'
          xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='/var/www/html/products.xsd'>
     <product>
          ...
     </product>
</products>
```

i want to replace /var/www/html with a variable 'path' for example, that has the value: '/var/www/html', so that i can change it whenever i want and still have the xsd file.
is that possible? and how is it done?

Comment: i'm working under netbeans, php